# Reading gpu load on both intel and nvidia

Tags: linux, nvidia

I am writing a daemon to automatically switch between my integrated graphics and dedicated graphics, in this case an nvidia MX150 and intel UHD 620.

so, i am trying to poll for 3D graphics load for both gpus so that the daemon can switch gpus, but after searching for a bit,i was not able to find something that will just output a number (EG: intel_gpu_top does not just give a number) and i do not want to install any other tools to get it working, is there any other way?